# I'm having issues with CardLayout and one of the JPanels not receiving Keyboard events

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout

I will only supply the relevant parts of the code as it is quite large. Help me figure out why I never get keyboard events to the GameBoard JPanel. The game code runs just fine until I added the new feature where I wanted it to have a welcome screen.

**Edit:** If you would like to view the entire project (it's an eclipse project), here is the link to download it [Eclipse project](https://www107.zippyshare.com/v/j8cWhwJQ/file.html), I honestly can't format almost 1000 lines of code here on StackOverflow, that'll be painful even for you.

Main.java

```
private void initUI() throws IOException {
    cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    mainPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
    
    welcomeMenu = new Welcome(cardLayout, mainPanel);
    mainPanel.add(welcomeMenu, "welcome");
    game = new GameBoard();
    mainPanel.add(game, "game");

    add(mainPanel);        
    setTitle("Pacman");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(380, 420);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

This is the welcome/menu panel (some section of it).
Welcome.java (servers as a menu)

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.EXIT.name()) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.CONFIG.name()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not yet implemented");
    } else if (evt.getActionCommand() == Actions.PLAY.name()) {
        // The part that switches to game, works as expected.
        cl.show(mp, "game");
    }
}
```

GameBoard class has a KeyAdapter class within it that is used to listen to key events, however, in the addition of the new feature using CardLayout, I could not get the key events to the panel so my PacMan is just stuck in one place opening and closing its mouth like a fish.

GameBoard.java

```
private void initBoard() {

    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());

    setFocusable(true);

    setBackground(Color.black);

    initGame();
}
...
class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
    
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (inGame) {
            if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                req_dx = -1;
                req_dy = 0;
            } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                req_dx = 1;
                req_dy = 0;
            } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                req_dx = 0;
                req_dy = -1;
            } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                req_dx = 0;
                req_dy = 1;
            } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE && timer.isRunning()) {
                inGame = false;
            } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_PAUSE) {
                if (timer.isRunning()) {
                    timer.stop();
                } else {
                    timer.start();
                }
            }
        } /*
             * else { if (key == 's' || key == 'S') { inGame = true; initGame(); } }
             */
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == Event.LEFT || key == Event.RIGHT || key == Event.UP || key == Event.DOWN) {
            req_dx = 0;
            req_dy = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I will only supply the relevant parts of the code as it is quite large."* When people discover the answer to the problem, they also commonly discover it was not in the parts of the code they thought were *relevant.* [Edit] to post a [mre]. Then we can be *sure* the relevant code is included. Voting to close on that basis, but note that the title suggests this should be two separate questions (with two separate MREs).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, the best I can do is send a link to the entire project. As I have already mentioned that the game works without the panel switching feature, it fails when I added the new feature. That's why I am only including the parts that are relevant to panel switching.

Comment: *"That's why I am only including the parts that are relevant to panel switching."* I'll expand on my further comment of 'relevance'. Is a solution relevant to you? Is it important? I ask because myself (and others) won't look closely at code until it is in our own IDEs, **compiled,** formatted to our usual expectation, and has been run once to prove that it displays the problem. But the thing is, this is only of relevance to you. For the rest of us, it is purely academic. So if *you* could not be bothered formulating an MRE, why should *we* be bothered trying to help?

Comment: *"best I can do is send a link to the entire project"* You have enough rep by now that you should realise that links to external resources are as frowned upon as code dumps. I.E. very much so. Minus one to help you remember not to even suggest such things in future.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I have linked the entire Eclipse project on my current edit. Could that help?

Comment: If best you can do is "send a link to the entire project" rather than making the needed effort to produce an [mre], the best I can do is help others that are willing to make that effort and make helping them easier.

Comment: *"don't see the point of copying more than 1000 lines of code"* You're really not paying attention to what I and @c0der are trying to communicate. If you post more dross like this, I will continue to down-vote and vote to close.

Comment: Sorry guys. I understand what you're saying, but I didn't have time to copy and format all those lines of code in here. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was using **Key Listener** when I should have been using **Key Binding** in the **GameBoard** JPanel. So instead of this,

```
class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (inGame) {
        ...
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            req_dx = 0;
            req_dy = -1;
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I replaced it with this approach (I will only demonstrate Arrow Up scenario),

```
private class UpAction extends AbstractAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!inGame)
            return;

        req_dx = 0;
        req_dy = -1;
    }
}

...

private void setupKeyListeners() {
    getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "doUp");
    ...

    getActionMap().put("doUp", new UpAction());
    ...
}
```

And later on,

```
private void initBoard() {

    setupListeners();
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(Color.black);
    initGame();
}
```